# Simple WCF service not getting called after deploying on different machine, however works fine on my local system

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I just tried to create a very simple wcf application. That is on a click of button i am trying to print "Hello World" on the page. I published the service and as again it works fine on my local system, but same when i try to deploy on server it doesn't. This application is damn simple, no complexities, not database connection, nothing. But still fails to call the service from the server. Checking on services,(Service1.svc -. Right Click -> Browse) works fine, but then why it fails to call through application, i don't know. Its getting rather more confusing now. Totally clueless on this. Posting all 3 necessary files used in the code.

web.config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
<services>
        <service name ="ApplicationReturnString.Web.Service1.svc">
          <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"/>
        </service>
      </services> 
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

ClientAccessPolicy.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource include-subpaths="true" path="/"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

CrossDomain.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM 
    "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

ServiceRefrence.ClientConfig file :

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:52731/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Suprising is, it doesn't display any error while clicking on the button or loading the page. But also the text "Hello world" is not getting displayed.

Comment: You need to set the endpoint address in the ServiceReference.client.config to the correct address. Run fiddler to see the silverlight application request.

Comment: Kindly setup the endpoint address in web.config file

Comment: Thanks Roy and Nitin. Actually the issue was on setting up endpoint address in web.config file and also as the services was getting deployed in other machine, the URL of the application was getting changed. So i made some important changes given below :

Comment: Thanks Roy & Nitin. Actually the issue was on setting up endpoint address in web.config file and also as the services was getting deployed in other machine, the URL of the application was getting changed. So i made some important changes given below: 1. Gave the endpoint address, endpoint name and Contract details in web.config file same as in ServiceRefrence.ClientConfig file. 2. Change the endpoint address in ServiceRefrence.ClientConfig without specific port details:<endpoint address="http://localhost/ServiceName.svc"> rather then <endpoint address="http://localhost:56717/ServiceName.svc">

Comment: and 3. Coded in the app to get the URI address of the machine where it executes so that wherever the app is deployed user has not to worry about the localhost address and its port details :                                    Uri servUri = new Uri("../Service.svc", UriKind.Relative);
            EndpointAddress servAddr = new EndpointAddress(servUri);
            ServiceReferenceForSelect.ServiceForSelectClient objSelect = new ServiceForSelectClient("BasicHttpBinding_IService", servAddr);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Roy & Nitin. Actually the issue was on setting up endpoint address in web.config file and also as the services was getting deployed in other machine, the URL of the application was getting changed. So i made some important changes given below: 1. Gave the endpoint address, endpoint name and Contract details in web.config file same as in ServiceRefrence.ClientConfig file. 2. Change the endpoint address in ServiceRefrence.ClientConfig without specific port details:; rather then ;and 3. Coded in the app to get the URI address of the machine where it executes so that wherever the app is deployed user has not to worry about the localhost address and its port details: Uri servUri = new Uri("../Service.svc", UriKind.Relative); EndpointAddress servAddr = new EndpointAddress(servUri); ServiceReferenceForSelect.ServiceForSelectClient objSelect = new ServiceForSelectClient("BasicHttpBinding_IService", servAddr);